# Alter style in JavaScript without affecting what gets rendered in the browser

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I extract several blocks that are spread across the page, draw them onto a canvas, via `Canvas​Rendering​Context2D.draw​Image()`, and then I export the canvas to PDF/JPG.

Now, while drawing them, I also want to tidy their looks and/or remove/display parts of some blocks, because the styling no longer makes sense from a static point of view.

I can append a class on `body`, style blocks differently while `body` has that class, build the canvas, export it to a content type of choice and remove `body` class, but this makes the page look quirky for 1 - 2 seconds. (I could just cover the page with a loader, I guess)

I can clone the block, style it differently or apply whatever styling (inline or via classes) and draw an image from that, but this is not optimal.

Any idea on how to do this properly? I'm inclined to go for something like emulation. Have the whole "export styling" under the native `@print` and emulate that before drawing the blocks onto the canvas, without affecting what gets rendered in the browser, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: What are you using to collect the DOM elements and pass them to Canvas? Javascript?

Comment: Yes, for plain HTML blocks I use https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/, for special cases (other canvases), I got my own handlers.

Comment: I can get rid of https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/, was asking as a proof of concept, how to properly alter style in JavaScript without altering the end result (what gets rendered in the browser).

Comment: Well you should get a collection of elements that you could attach a class to for only the brief amount of time it takes to process them. Using canvas means you're essentially copying the elements anyway so once the element is added to canvas you could remove the class from the element. *All said without digging into html2canvas...*

Answer (score 1):

I know these don't answer your specific question, but perhaps these are viable alternatives to the problem.

It sounds like you're trying to make something printable. I assume this is triggered by a user interaction of some kind so...

This means you have a few interface options. For example, you could "hide" the screen by placing a modal over the entire thing with a message that says "processing just a moment". Then the body (or another element) class solution works.

You could copy the elements as you suggested. If you go that route I would move the copies off the screen while you change them.

```
 .element {
   position: fixed;
   left: -100vw;
 }
```

Without knowing how many duplicates you need to make it's hard to recommend this option.

Alternately, could you offload the effort to a [`service worker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)? This would require a copy into memory BUT its completely detached from the DOM and runs in a different thread.

It's a really interesting problem though!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is something similar to print, but besides the HTML blocks, I also have to prepare some canvases (that got pan, zoom and UI themselves), so it's not just print (which I generally associate with CSS). Say you got a map and the user zoomed a specific city, the static asset that gets exported needs to include the full map, not where the user's at. I think a huge ass loader is enough for now, I will revisit this and try workers at some point in the future.

Comment: @Ravenous Yup, I get the use case. You're lucky that it's from user interaction. People kind of expect some sort of loading/processing feedback or at least it's not surprising to them.

Comment: Since no one provided a different answer, you deserve the bounty. I got it working, nonetheless, was just curious of how others would approach this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `node.cloneNode(true)` to make a deep clone for all these blocks, put them in a classname scoped common root that's hide away from user's view, then you mod their style secretly.

Since you mod the cloned version of nodes, the original remains untouched. Plus, using the classname scope, your css can target these clones accurately.